# All radio buttons are checked by default in Next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am having a big brain freeze. In my component I am using custom radio buttons that renders out a chart based on which button is pressed.

```
const NameOfComponent = () => {
  const [yearsBack, setYearsBack] = useState(1);

  return (
          <div>
            <RadioButton
              label="1 year"
              value={1}
              checked={yearsBack === 1}
              name="date-range-radio-group"
              onChange={() => setYearsBack(1)}
            />
            <RadioButton
              label="2 years"
              value={2}
              checked={yearsBack === 2}
              name="date-range-radio-group"
              onChange={() => setYearsBack(2)}
            />
            <RadioButton
              label="3 years"
              value={3}
              checked={yearsBack === 3}
              name="date-range-radio-group"
              onChange={() => setYearsBack(3)}
            />
          </div>
     );
};

export default NameOfComponent;
```

The issue I am having is that all three radio buttons are checked by default, I only want the first one to be checked by default and then unchecked if I press another radio button. How do I fix this when the value is a number? If it was a string I understand I would have to do `onChange={(e) => setYearsBack(e.target.value)}`  Please let me know if you need further information, I have not added the entire component, only what I think is most important for this issue.

Comment: From where this `RadioButton` is coming?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar it is a custom component. const RadioButton = forwardRef(
  ({ label, checked, value, onChange, name, className = '' }) => {
    const id = useId();
    return (
      <>
        <input
          className="sr-only peer"
          type="radio"
          id={id}
          checked={checked}
          value={value}
          name={name}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <label className={`radio-button ${className}`} ref={ref} htmlFor={id}>
          {label}
        </label>
      </>
    );
  },
);

Comment: It's working fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-pasteur-2r77lk?file=/src/App.js.